# Cannot connect to hotspot with usb wifi device in linux

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, usb

There are three things which is going wrong in my connection

1. The wlan0 which is in most of the SO question is getting renamed to wlx20e317024622
2. The connection is there when checked through iwconfig but there is not internet access.
3. The error *aborting authentication with x by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)*

Please help
Sorry for my wrong english.

Comment: The naming conventions for network devices have changed so [your wlx* is likely normal](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Networking_Guide/sec-Understanding_the_Predictable_Network_Interface_Device_Names.html). What is the authentication type required for the Wifi? And if there is one, have you tried to connect to an "open" Wifi?

Comment: if it's connected but not for 'internet access' you either have no gateway set, or no addess set via dhcp or static+gateway, or your gateway isnt functioning.

Comment: @sirex how do I check is gateway is set or not

Comment: route -n  and look for 0.0.0.0 (or whatever subnet youre trying to ping) or ip route and look for default. I'm guessing you'll not have a network address either and it's not actually asked for one from your DHCP server at all. esp if other clients work.

Comment: Nothing is being shown in with above commands, I feel like iwconfig is faking connection